# Firebase user delete with GoogleSign, ID Token is stale to sign-in

Tags: android, firebase

Firebase user delete with Google Sign but it have error : ID Token issued at ~~ is stale to sign-in, when reauthenticate currentuser before delete

```
    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(SettingActivity.this);
                        credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
                        currentUser.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    currentUser.delete()
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                        googleSignOut();
                                                        choiceDialog.dimissDialog();
                                                        ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(SettingActivity.this);
                                                        Intent intent = new Intent(SettingActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                        startActivity(intent);
                                                    }
                                                    else{
                                                        Log.d("Delete user with google", "delete error : " + task.getException().toString() );
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                                else{
                                    Log.d("Delete user with google", "reAuth error : " + task.getException().toString() );
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Here is expetion for the application

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ ID Token issued at 1570352462 is stale to sign-in. ]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution?